# sequences above 0,1,2 start&end with 0 with no 2 same successive digits

Tags: combinatorics

find the number of sequences of length n above {0,1,2} that start and end with 0 and without 2 successive digits that are equal (00,11,22).
Find and solve a recursice equation.

I would be thankful for a clue or an approach to this.

Comment: Infinite? If I repeat 0120120120120120... I can always make the sequence longer by appending another 120.

Comment: of length n, forgot to mention this. edited.

Comment: If you ignore the "end with zero" condition, the first number must be zero and for each successive number you have two options.  Applying multiplication principle yields $2^{n-1}$ total strings of length $n$.  The condition that the final term must be zero as well throws this off a bit, but approximately a third of them will end in a zero, giving the assymptotic nature as $\sim \frac{1}{3}2^{n-1}$

Comment: That being said, you can run two recursive sequences simultaneously.  Let $a_n$ count the number of sequences of length $n$ which both start and end with zero satisfying your conditions and let $b_n$ count the number of sequences of length $n$ satisfying all of your conditions *except* that it ends with zero, i.e. that sequences counted by $b_n$ may or may not end with a zero.  I just described how to count $b_n$.  Now, what does $b_n-a_n$ represent and how is it useful to us in coming up with a formula for $a_{n+1}$?

Comment: ok so after following what you suggested, I got a recursive equation that I've tried to solve using the iteration method...but it got a bit complex after getting a series inside it. Do it supposed to be eventually what you wrote in your first comment? (the solution of the recursive equation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We define a recurrence relation as follows. Let
>
> - $a_k$ denote the number of valid strings with $k$-th symbol $0$.
> - $b_k$ denote the number of valid strings with $k$-th symbol $1$.
> - $c_k$ denote the number of valid strings with $k$-th symbol $2$.

Since valid strings start with $0$ we have
\begin{align*}
a_1=1\qquad b_1=0\qquad c_1=0\tag{1}
\end{align*}

Valid strings do not have equal consecutive characters. The recurrence relation for $2\leq k\leq n-1$ is
\begin{align*}
a_k&=b_{k-1}+c_{k-1}\\
b_k&=a_{k-1}+c_{k-1}\tag{2}\\
c_k&=a_{k-1}+b_{k-1}
\end{align*}
and since the $n$-th character of a valid string is $0$, we have for $n\geq 2$:
\begin{align*}
a_n=b_{n-1}+c_{n-1}\tag{3}
\end{align*}

> We are looking for $a_n, n\geq 0$.
>
> Due to the symmetry of $b_n$ and $c_n$ in the recurrence relations (1) - (3) we observe $b_n=c_n, n\geq 1$ and we obtain a simplified recurrence relation
>
> \begin{align*}
> a_1&=1, b_1=0\\
> a_k&=2b_{k-1}\qquad\qquad 2\leq k\leq n-1\tag{4}\\
> b_k&=a_{k-1}+b_{k-1}\\
> a_n&=2b_{n-1}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}
>
> We obtain from (4) a recurrence relation for $b_k, k\geq 1$.
>   \begin{align*}
> b_1&=0, b_2=1\\
> b_k&=b_{k-1}+2b_{k-2}\qquad\qquad k\geq 3\tag{6}
> \end{align*}
>
> Setting $B(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_kx^k$ we obtain from (6)
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=3}^\infty b_kx^k&=\sum_{k=3}^\infty b_{k-1}x^k+2\sum_{k=3}b_{k-2}x^k\\
> &=x\sum_{k=2}^\infty b_{k}x^k+2x^2\sum_{k=1}b_{k}x^k\\
> B(x)-x^3&=xB(x)+2x^2B(x)\\
> \color{blue}{B(x)}&\color{blue}{=\frac{x^3}{1-x-2x^2}}
> \end{align*}
>
> Since $a_n=2b_{n-1}$ according to (5), we finally obtain for $n\geq 2$
>   \begin{align*}
> a_n&=2[x^{n-1}]B(x)\\
> &=2[x^n]xB(x)\\
> &=[x^n]\frac{2x^3}{1-x-2x^2}\\
> &=[x^n]\left(2 x^3 + 2 x^4 + 6 x^5 + \color{blue}{10} x^6 + 22 x^7 + 42 x^8 + \cdots\right)
> \end{align*}

The last line was calculated with some help of Wolfram Alpha.

> The coefficient $\color{blue}{10}$ of $x^6$ for example tells us we have $10$ valid strings
>   \begin{align*}
> &010120,010210,012010,012020,012120,\\
> &020120,020210,021010,021020,021210
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

It's the number of closed walks on the graph $K_3$.  So if we define
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
then it's the number in cell $(1,1)$ of $A^n$.

Computing this gives
$$
0, 2, 2, 6, 10, 22, 42, 86, 170, 342, 682, \ldots
$$
when $n \geq 1$, which is OEIS's [A078008](http://oeis.org/A078008).

There's a linear recurrence given there
$$
a(n) = 3a(n-2) + 2a(n-3)
$$
which follows directly from the identity
$$
A^4 = 3A^2+2A.
$$
And if we use the usual methods for [solving linear recurrences](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearRecurrenceEquation.html), we'd get the closed form solution at OEIS:
$$
a(n) = \frac{1}{3}(2^n + 2(-1)^n).
$$